# Xpath of checkbox inside iframe inside div

Tags: xpath

for the life of me, I cannot get the xpath of this....
i think the problem is that there are two divs one, called 'div_settings_A' and 'div_settings_C', in the example below you cant see the 'div_settings_C' because its hidden, just cant put my finger on why it wont work!

I have tried

> //div[contains(@id, 'div_settings_A')]/input 
>   //tr[@id='inputSavePaymentAccounts'] and td[@name='payAck']

```
<iframe id="ccPayWiz" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" src="ccxPaymentDetails.php?c=1805&a=733344&d=null&m=Automation@billtrust.com&b=768866910" style="width: 99%; min-height: 105.833px; height: 717px; position: relative;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <body style="border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" onload="setuppanes('IG');">
                <input id="wpsURL" type="hidden" value="WPS_URL">
                    <form id="frmPay" onsubmit="return paywizAccountHelper.validateForm(this, '17', 'US');" action="ccProcessPayment.php" method="post" name="frmPay">
                        <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="e5297f08b85318aa2ec176a5d8fac2a2">
                            <div id="divPayWizard2">
                                <div style="float:left; margin-top:5px">
                                    <ul class="steps ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
                                        <li>
                                            <li>
                                                <li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <br clear="all">
                                                <hr>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <span class="cc-font"> Enter the customer's billing information to process the payment.</span>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <div id="divpane1">
                                                        <table id="tablepane1" class="cc-pane1-table cc-font">
                                                            <br>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div id="divpane2">
                                                                <table class="cc-pane2-table-top cc-font">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div id="div_settings_A" style="display: block;">
                                                                    <input type="hidden" value="733344" name="SrchAcctNum">
                                                                        <table class="cc-font" width="700" cellspacing="3" border="0">
                                                                            <input id="BankCountry" type="hidden" value="US" name="BankCountry">
                                                                                <tbody>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                                                        <tr id="inputSavePaymentAccounts" class="savePaymentAccounts" style="display: table-row;">
                                                                                                                            <td class="addCCLabel" style="padding-top: 15px">Save this Payment Method</td>
                                                                                                                            <td style="padding-top: 15px">
                                                                                                                                <input class="payAck" type="checkbox" name="payAck" style="margin: 0; padding 0" tabindex="9">
                                                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                                            </tr>
```

Comment: Have you typed `//div[contains(@div='div_settings_A']/input` equals as you're using? Because there is a syntax error here. You does not close the contains parentheses neither select any to compare

Comment: You have a typo, it is surely meant to be `//div[contains(@id, 'div_settings_A')]`, right? See the `@id` instead of the `@div`.

Comment: yeah thats a typo i would have gotten a malformed xpath error, if that was the case

Comment: the above suggestions did not work, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly get that ccheck box element by using  name attribute as :

```
.//input[@type = 'checkbox' and @name = 'payAck']
```

Or if there are multiple check boxes with the same name then try using `descendant` of `tr` as :

```
.//tr[@id = 'inputSavePaymentAccounts']/descendant::input[@type = 'checkbox' and @name = 'payAck']
```

Or

```
.//tr[@id = 'inputSavePaymentAccounts']/descendant::input
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: question for ya: after using the xpath you provided, at run time, the automation checkmarks the box however in the GUI the checkbox never gets "checked" and ideas?

Comment: @TheBugCollector I think you need to ask another question regarding this with your tried attempt. Thanks..:)

Comment: to make this more clearer, the first screen shot is the checkbox http://prnt.sc/c12b1p   the next screenshot is whats suppose to happen when the checkbox is checked http://prnt.sc/c12b7q    (basically a textbox is suppose to appear once the checbox is checked) however the issue is for some reason the gui wont reflect the xpath getting "checked"  with no error thrown that the xpath is "bad"